# Mongoose cant save model arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to do this:

var hStatus = require('models/hStatus');

```
var log = new hLog();

    hStatus.find({_id: /^value_/}, function(err, data){
            if(!err){
                    log.h = data;
                    log.save(function(err){
                         if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                         }else{
                            console.log('ok!');
                         }
                    });
            }
    });
```

data var structure:

```
[ { outs: 
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    c: 1457739456474,
    b: false,
    c: true,
    d: false },
```

my models are:

```
var hLog = new mongoose.Schema({
        a: Date,
        b: Number,
        c: String,
        d: String,
        e: Boolean,
        f: Boolean,
        g: String,
        h: [hStatus]
});

//this two same file
var hOuts = new mongoose.Schema({
        a: Number,
        b: String,
        c: Boolean,
        d: Boolean
});

var hStatus = new mongoose.Schema({
        a: String,
        b: Boolean,
        Outs: [hOuts],
        c: Number,
        d: Boolean   
});
```

But the save function returns:

**ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Array failed for value at "{ Outs:**

Is this the right way to do it?

Im not sure what I missing.

Comment: in your hLog model, change  h: [hStatus] to h: {} and see if that works. not a fix to the problem, just try and see.

Comment: yup, saved ok. Can you explain to me why? thanks!!

Comment: your schema has errors. please look at my new answer below

Comment: Thats not it I just copied the field wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **.push()** method:

```
var log = new hLog();

    hStatus.findOne({_id: /^value_/}, function(err, data){
            if(!err){
                    log.h.push(data);
                    log.save(function(err){
                         if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                         }else{
                            console.log('ok!');
                         }
                    });
            }
    });
```

Comment: Tried, got this:
TypeError: this._schema.caster.cast is not a function

Comment: try using findOne(), that retrieve one object instead of find() retrieve array of objects

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
...
log.h = data;
log.markModified('h');
log.save(function(err){
                     if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                     }else{
                        console.log('ok!');
                     }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have errors in hStatus Schema

```
c: Number,
d: Boolean
```

while in your json data

```
...
c: true,
d: 'asd'
```

types don't match

Comment: I just copied wrong, fixed on the edit. Still your {} in the model fixes it.